# Python scrapy: the second function don't call

Tags: python, scrapy

I am written a scrapy code. I want extract the links for the pages I am interested, follow them and then extract the data I want for all of them. But function parse_item don't work. Help me please to find a mistakes.

```
import scrapy
import logging
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from activesport.items import ActivesportItem


configure_logging(install_root_handler=False)
logging.basicConfig(
   filename='log.txt',
   format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
   level=logging.INFO
)

class ActivesportSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "activesport"
    allowed_domains = ["http://activesport.co/"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-  e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Bikes_Frames",
        "http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories",
        "http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components",
        "http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Apparel",
        "http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Tech"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
       """Retrieve data out from section's catalogue - the second level"""
        self.logger.info('&&Visited on %s', response.url)
        #Extract link to the second level section, follow them                                                                                                                                                     
        for link in response.xpath('//div[@class="InfoArea"]/h3/a/@href'):
            url = response.urljoin(link.extract())
            self.logger.info('&&The second level section url %s', (url))
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        """Extract all data about the particular item"""
        self.logger.info('&&Item parse function %s', response.url)
        for items_title in response.xpath('//h3[@class="TopPaddingWide"]/a/text()').extract():
           yield {'title': items_title}
```

Output:

```
    2016-07-29 19:48:18 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
    []
    2016-07-29 19:48:18 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
    2016-07-29 19:48:18 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0  pages/min),    scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
    2016-07-29 19:48:18 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on   127.0.0.1:6023
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET  http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30- e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories> (referer: None)
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Bikes_Frames> (referer: None)
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Apparel> (referer: None)
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&Visited on http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Bags_Luggage
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'activesport.co': <GET http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Bags_Luggage>
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Bar_Ends
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Bells__Horns
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Bike_Bags
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Bike_Frame_Protection
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Bike_Racks__Carriers
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Bottle_Cages
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Cameras
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Child_Seats
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Child_Trailers_and_Tagalong
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/%22Computers%2C%20GPS%22
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Cool_Stuff
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Lights
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Locks
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Lubricants
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Mudguards
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Pannier_Racks
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Phone_Accessories
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Pumps
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Sledge
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Tents
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Tools__Workshop
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Trailers
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Trainers
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Water_Bottles
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Accessories/Workstand
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Tech> (referer: None)
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&Visited on http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Bikes_Frames
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Bikes_Frames/Bikes
    2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Bikes_Frames/Frames
   2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Bikes_Frames/Scooters
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&Visited on http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Apparel
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Apparel/Apparel_Care_Products
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Apparel/Body_Armour
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Apparel/Glasses
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Apparel/Gloves
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Apparel/Hats
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Apparel/Helmets
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Apparel/Hoody
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Apparel/Jackets
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Apparel/Jersey
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Apparel/Legwear
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Apparel/Shoes
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Apparel/Shoe_Covers
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Apparel/Socks
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Apparel/Tee
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Products/DMR-T-V12-G-S
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Products/DMR-T-14-BRUSH-SB
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Products/DMR-HC1-BRUSH-SGL    
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Products/DMR-H1-BRUSH-SBO
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&Visited on http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Tech
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Tech/Crank_Brothers_Manuals
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Tech/Middleburn_Manuals
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Tech/Tacx_Trainer_Spare_Parts_Manuals
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Tech/Tacx_Repair_Stands_Spare_Parts_Manual
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Tech/Thule_Chariot_Trailers
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Tech/Hope_Manuals
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components> (referer: None)
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&Visited on http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Bar_Tape
  2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Bearings
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Bike_Frame_Parts
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Bottom_Bracket
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Brake
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Cassette__Freewheel__Sprockets
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Chain
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Chain_Device
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Chainrings
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Chainsets
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Derailleurs
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Forks
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Fox_Spares
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Gear_Shifters
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Grips
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Handle_Bars
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Headset
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Middleburn
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Pedals
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Rear_Mech_Hanger
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Rear_Suspension
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Saddles
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Seatposts
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Stems
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Tyres_Tubes_Puncture_Repair
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Wheel_Components
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Wheels
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Gear_Cable
 2016-07-29 19:48:19 [activesport] INFO: &&The second level section url http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Components/Scooter_Spares
```

Comment: What is the output when you call the script? Please edit your Question and add the scrapy output. Without knowing the output I'd guess that the format of allowed_domains prevents your spider from working. That parameter should be without protocol specifiaction!

Comment: Thank you. The scrapy output was added.

Comment: Are you sure your xpaths find anything?

Comment: In [1]:   response.xpath('//h3[@class="TopPaddingWide"]/a/text()').extract()
Out[1]: 
[u'Claud Butler Touriste Tandem Bike 2014',
u'Claud Butler PHOBOS 20" Junior Bike 2016',
u'CBR Storm Boys Mountain Bike 2014',
u'Claud Butler Cambridge Pink Ladies Bike 2016',
   
In [2]: response.url 
Out[2]: 'http://activesport.co/epages/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/80c85f8f-7a95-4b1c-9c30-e64b314f3f2e/Categories/Bikes_Frames/Bikes'

Comment: Thank you for adding the beginning of the output. Could you add also the end (with the summary of scrapy operations). You can leave out the lines where things repeat of course. I'm especially interested how many pages are filtered. Did you notice that there is such a offsite statement in your output?

Comment: Thank you for your help and for your comments. ))) I found a mistake. It was in a string  "allowed_domains"  - uncorrect data format. It was fixed. Code work fine.